# Difference between .html and .ssi

Tags: html, ssi

What is the main difference between .html and .ssi? In what kinds of situations should I use .ssi (server side include)? I'd love examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSI is also  other server pages like ASP, JSP, PHP which runs and processed in server side.
 Some servers capable of running SSI files like Nucleus Web server etc.
The SSI file can contain all the tags or code as like HTML. Optionally can include server side tags to be processed from server.

If you dont have any server side calls, then should create simple HTML file.

Answer (score 3):

The following links are help to identify the difference between html and ssi.

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341/SSI-The-Include-Command.htm

http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/398290.html